# facebook graph api sharedpost get amount of likes from the page that shared

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the sharedpost endpoint to retrieve the pages that shared my post like this:

```
{post_id}/sharedposts?fields=likes.summary(1),id,created_time,from.summary(1)&limit=1500
```

This will return the data like:

```
{
  "id": "{sharedpost_id}",
  "created_time": "2017-05-13T23:01:51+0000",
  "from": {
    "name": "Page that shared",
    "id": "Id of page that shared"
  },
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 0,
      "can_like": false,
      "has_liked": false
    }
  }
}
```

Now some posts get a shitload of shares so I want to filter only the shares by pages that have above a certain amount of likes.

Now I can make a second call to the api which asks for the amount of likes but I hope it would be possible to do this in the same request.

So The desired output would be:

```
 {
  "id": "{sharedpost_id}",
  "created_time": "2017-05-13T23:01:51+0000",
  "from": {
    "name": "Page that shared",
    "id": "Id of page that shared"
    "likes: : "Likes of the page that shared"
  },
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 0,
      "can_like": false,
      "has_liked": false
    }
  }
}
```

So with the likes of the page included in the from.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done using [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion):

```
/post-id/sharedposts?fields=from{name,fan_count}
```

And if you need this not only for single posts, but for all posts in a page’s feed, you can also move that “one level up”, like so:

```
/page-id/feed?fields=sharedposts{from{name,fan_count}}
```

---

I am not exactly sure if that still works, if you also get shared posts by users returned - in that case it *might* throw an error, that `fan_count` is not an existing field on the user object.
This would only be relevant for posts shared by users that have logged in to your app, and granted it `user_posts` permission (because only then would you see those posts show in the sharedposts edge in the first place) - so if that is not applicable in your situation, it will be fine; otherwise I suggest you test this case before relying on it.

Comment: I have another small problem with this. fan count obvioulsy only applies to pages. But not all shares are from pages. So this results in a error `Caught exception: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (fan_count) on node type (User)` Is there a way to work around this error?

Comment: Well that is exactly what I said might happen ... In that case, I am afraid you might have to make individual requests. You could look for another way to figure out which are pages and which are user profiles first - and then assemble requests using the `?ids=id1,id2,id3` syntax to at least request that data for multiple page ids in one go.

Comment: Hmm yeah. but they havent granted me permission. the app isnt even public but stills returns some user shares. I guess it has something to do with the privacy settings of a user. But yeah. ill just have to do it that way! thanks for the help agian!

Comment: I have another question which isnt really code related, but you seem to know a lot about the facebook api. Is there any chance I can contact you for the question?

Comment: If it doesn't fit here, because it is too little programming-related, then I suggest you join the FB Developers Group and ask there, https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/